# How to clear marks permanently in Vim?

Tags: vim

`:delm a-zA-Z0-9`

does clear all marks, but when I close the file and reopen the marks still exists.How to clear all the marks permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen, if you have a second vim instance open, that will write the viminfo file and effectively re-adding the mark back to the viminfo file. So you either need to clear the mark in all vim instances, or try to synchronize the reading and writing of the viminfo file. [This link from the faq](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-17.3) should work.

Comment: I've only one Vim instance open. In that I executed :delm A-Z0-9. It did clear all marks. But, when I reopen the file, the marks persist.

Comment: Try explicitly rewriting the viminfo file using `:wviminfo`

Comment: Executed :wviminfo but nothing happened. Where will that viminfo file be located?

Comment: Write the viminfo file, after you cleared the mark. Your viminfo file usually is located below your $HOME directory. You might want to check manually with the :marks command and inspect your .viminfo file manually, if the mark is gone.

Comment: Deleted the marks explicitly in _viminfo file -> Save & Exit. Opened _viminfo only to find the marks still present!

Comment: use vim -u NONE -N -i NONE before editing your .viminfo file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87582/discussion-between-sagar-jain-and-christian-brabandt).

Comment: in neovim (not vim!) I needed `:wshada!` to permanently clear the marks, see https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/7198#issuecomment-323649157

Answer (score 2):

Try `:delmarks!`

> If you delete a line containing a mark, the mark is also deleted.
>
> If you wipeout a buffer (command :bw), all marks for the buffer are deleted.
>
> The :delmarks command (abbreviated as :delm) may be used to delete specified marks.

```
Command         Description
:delmarks a     delete mark a
:delmarks a-d   delete marks a, b, c, d
:delmarks abxy  delete marks a, b, x, y
:delmarks aA    delete marks a, A
:delmarks!      delete all lowercase marks for the current buffer (a-z)
```

[wiki for Using_marks](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks)